# effect of Jahn-Tellar distortion in energy bands

Tags: quantum-spin

Is orbital degeneracy same as electronic degeneracy? When we mean bands are degenerate, is it like the bands are doubled or single? After Jahn-Tellar distortion what will happen to the energy bands?